# ¿Por qué no entra al if?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Hola estoy leyendo un archivo de tipo csv en Python, lo logre leer pero no me entra a la condicional, le adjunto el código, también le dejo una imagen del csv para que vean el archivo (No se como adjuntarlo), de antemano muchas gracias.

```
def filtrarAnio(anio):
archivo = open("o.csv","r")
for linea in archivo:
    fecha = str(linea.split(",")[5]) # lee la sexta columna del csv (recordar que parte de la posicion 0)
    fechaNueva = fecha[6:len(fecha)-4] # En la lectura del csv la fecha tiene el formato "2020JAN" se elimina el mes y solamente se deja el año
    #print(fechaNueva,anio)
    if fechaNueva == anio:
        print("entre")
        ContaminacionAnual.append(linea.split(",")[-1])
print(ContaminacionAnual)
```

[image: formato del csv]

Comment: Apuesto que `anoi` es numérico ...

Answer (score 1):

## Problemas

1 - Error en la identación, en Python las funciones se deben escribir de la siguiente manera respetando los espacios:

```
def funcion():
    print("mi funcion")
    return
```

2 - Abres el archivo csv pero no lo cierras, en ves de hacer `archivo = open("o.csv","r")` es mejor si utilizas lo siguiente que al concluir cierra automáticamente el archivo:

```
 with open("o.csv","r") as archivo:
        for linea in archivo:
```

2 - En la segunda línea de tu archivo csv falta una coma, esto causa un error `IndexError: list index out of range` debido a que aquí `fecha = str(linea.split(",")[5])` especificas que esperas que cada línea del csv tenga 5 columnas.

3 - Entiendo lo que querías lograr con esto `fecha[6:len(fecha)-4]` pero la forma correcta de hacerlo es `fecha[0:5]` para más información sobre como hacer slice en strings ve [aquí](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3).

4 - Suponiendo que todo lo anterior estuviera bien seguirías sin entrar al `if` porque la condición que especificaste es `if "2020" == 2020` que siempre devolverá falso. Debes convertir la stringa en número entero antes de hacer la comparación, pero como a veces recibes letras en vez de números el programa podría romperse, para impedirlo necesitarás atrapar estos errores con lo siguiente:

```
try:
    fechaNueva=int(fechaNueva)
except:
    pass
```

## Solución

Todos estos consejos una vez corregidos quedarían de la siguiente manera (sin olvidarnos de añadir la coma en la segunda línea del csv):

```
ContaminacionAnual=[]

def filtrarAnio(anio):
    with open("S:\Projects\StackOverflow-Tests\o.csv","r") as archivo:
        for linea in archivo:
            fecha = str(linea.split(",")[5]) # lee la sexta columna del csv (recordar que parte de la posicion 0)
            fechaNueva = fecha[0:5] # En la lectura del csv la fecha tiene el formato "2020JAN" se elimina el mes y solamente se deja el año 
            
            try:
                fechaNueva=int(fechaNueva)
            except:
                pass
            
            if fechaNueva == anio:
                print("entre")
                ContaminacionAnual.append(linea.split(",")[-1])

filtrarAnio(2020)
print(ContaminacionAnual)
```